# Converting html entity to text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-entities, html-parsing

I have `&#146;` in my HTML file (which is a right curly quote) and I want to convert it to text (if possible).

I tried using HTMLParser and BeautifulSoup but to no success.

```
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape("&#39;")
u"'"
>>> h.unescape("&#146;")
u'\x92' # I was hoping for a right curly quote here.
```

My goal is very simple: Take the html input and output all the text (without any html codes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"right curly quote" is not an ascii character. `u'\x92'` is the python representation of the unicode character representing it and not some "html code".

To display it properly in your terminal, use `print h.unescape("&#146;").encode('utf-8')` (or whatever you terminal's charset is).